# Barra de ajuste de valores

Tags: php, javascript, html, vue.js

Pessoal gostaria de saber se existe algum componente pronto na internet que me faça um elemento parecido com esse da imagem abaixo gostaria de saber qual o nome desse componente também para que eu possa saber como ele funciona e onde devo acha-lo.

Provavelmente teria que usar VUE.js mais se ouver algo como isso nesse framework e puderem me ajudar agradeço.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Componentes com esse estilo ou com essa funcionalidade?

Comment: Tem o [*range* do HTML 5](http://www.html5tutorial.info/html5-range.php) que faz isso.

Answer (score 2):

Se você procura um slider como esse, junto a um contador, recomendo frameworks como `Angular.Js`, `React.Js` e `Vue.Js`

Elas contam com uma vasta biblioteca de componentes baseadas em [Material Designer](https://material.io/guidelines/#)

Slider em [Angular Material](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/slider)

Slider em [React Material](http://www.material-ui.com/#/components/slider)

Slide em [Vue Material](https://vuetifyjs.com/components/sliders)

Comment: eu queria usar o vue.js amigo tem algum link para me indicar que mostre como se faz isso via Vue.js

Comment: No link acima tem todas as informações de como usar os componentes, inclusive no vue, segue um link de exemplo https://github.com/vuetifyjs/docs/blob/master/examples/sliders/4.vue